# Looping a specific amount of times, each time making a new list

Tags: python, list, loops

Basically what I want to do is have a program that makes a list based on user input, such as:

```
a=input
b=input
c=input

list1=[a,b,c]
```

then have it do it again (forming list2) and again and so on, until it reaches list37, where I want to make a list of lists, such as:

```
listMASTER=[list1,list2,list3...list36]
```

I don't want to write this:

```
a=input
b=input
c=input

listn=[a,b,c]
```

36 times, so I want it to loop over and over again with each time forming a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
outer_listen = []
n = 36 #Or howmany ever times you want to loop
for i in range(n): #0 through 35
    a = input()
    b = input()
    c = input()
    lstn = [a, b, c]
    outer_listen.append(lstn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to do it easily:

```
olist=[]
for i in range(n): #n is the number of items you need the list (as in your case, 37)
    lis=[input(),input(),input()]
    olist.append(lis)
```

This will reduce the number of steps

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested loops:

```
list_of_lists = [[input() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(36)]
```

Or more conveniently, also accept the input from a file e.g., using csv format:

```
a,b,c
d,f,g
...
```

Corresponding code:

```
import csv
import fileinput

list_of_lists = list(csv.reader(fileinput.input()))
```

Usage:

```
$ python make-list.py input.csv
```

Or

```
$ echo a,b,c | python make-list.py
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit dense but still readable with a list comprehension

```
n = 36
prompt = 'Please enter for {}{}: '
all_inputs = [[input(prompt.format(char, num)) for char in 'abc'] 
               for num in range(n)]
print(all_inputs)
```

Gives you 36 x 3 input prompts:

```
Please enter for a0: 1
Please enter for b0: 2
Please enter for c0: 3
Please enter for a1: 4
Please enter for b1: 5
Please enter for c1: 6
...
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
master = [[input(),input(),input()] for i in xrange(37)]
```